# Periodic process stalls

Tags: raspbian, gpio, c++

Was wondering if anyone is familiar with this - I've got the RPi working as an LED controller, sending digital color data 60 times per second to some WS2801 LED controller chips. Everything's working fine - I'm using c++ and the bcm2835 library for GPIO, and the process just sends 3 quick bytes over 2 GPIO pins then sleeps the remainder of the 1/60 sec - except for a weird intermittent problem:

Every minute or two, the Pi will go into a weird pattern where it stalls for 1 second, then resumes for 1 second, stalls for 1 sec, resumes 1 sec, repeating this anywhere from 2 to 30 times before resuming normally. The 1-second on/off is very precise.

Not sure what this stall is exactly - I've got a rapid blink pattern (30 blinks/sec) running to help troubleshoot. Normally the blinks are smooth, except during the stall, where the light is stuck on or off for 1 second intervals - this is how it would behave if GPIO data stopped outputting during the interval, so I assume that's what's happening.

Any ideas? Weirdly when I run "top" to see if it's a background process, the stalls never happen. Only when "top" isn't running.

Comment: OK, stupid coding mistake here. My timing was based on gettimeofday(), and I was assuming the microsecond portion could be used alone. But I needed to multiply the "second" portion by 1,000,000 and add that in also. So not doing that caused some weird problems.

Comment: Hi and welcome @QuadrupleA to raspberry pi stackexchange. If you have managed to solve your own question, move your comment into an answer of it's own rather than a comment, then you can select it (in a couple of days) as the correct answer. This helps us not have unanswered questions!

Comment: Unfortunately StackExchange doesn't let me provide answers yet - that was the first thing I tried :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the privilege to answer my own questions, so here's the earlier comment:

Stupid coding mistake here. My timing was based on gettimeofday(), and I was assuming the microsecond portion could be used alone. But I needed to multiply the "second" portion by 1,000,000 and add that in also. So not doing that caused some weird problems.